# Function and its gradient in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gradient, convex-optimization

I am working on a **Matlab** project and I want to make the gradient of the following function in Matlab:

```
f(x) = c^T * x - sum (log(bi - (ai ^ T) * x)).
```

Where `ai^T` are the rows of a random A matrix nxm , where `n=2`, and `m=20`
c is random matrix nx1, and x is also random nx1. 
b is random matrix mx1.
I've done the following but the results i get don't seem to be right..

```
function gc0 = gc(x, c, b, A)

 for k = 1 : length(A(:,1))
     f1(k) = sum(log(b - A(k,:)'*x(k)));
 end

 gradient(-f1)
 gc0 = c - gradient(f1)';
```

Any ideas? I'd appreciate your help, I'm newbie in Matlab..

Comment: I assume you need `b(k)`. Also `A(k,:).'` just in case. `log` is not `log10` in case you need that one. You are neither transposing `c`, nor multiplying it by `x`

Comment: I am not transposing c nor multiplying it by x because gc0 is the gradient of f that i want to make and gradient of c^T *x is c..

Comment: But the gradient of `sum (log(bi - (ai ^ T) * x))` is not `sum (log(bi - (ai ^ T) * x))`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your loop contains a mistake. Looking at the formula above,
I think that the function evaluation should be

```
f1 = c'*x;
for k = 1 : length(A(1,:))
    f1 = f1 - log(b(k) - A(:,k)'*x)
end
```

A shorter and faster notation for this in Matlab is

```
f = c'*x - sum(log(b - A' * x)) ;
```

The function 'gradient' does not calculate the gradient that I think you
want: it returns the differences of matrix entries, and your function f
is a scalar.

Instead, I suggest calculating the derivatives symbolically:

```
Gradf = c'   + sum( A'./(b - A' * x) );
```